# ngx-datatable header cell tooltip

Tags: angular, header, tooltip

Is there possible to add material tooltip or other tooltip to [ngx-datatable](https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-datatable/content/) header cell?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a header Template for your column you could add anything. Check the Templates demos in ngx-datatable project
https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/templates/template-obj.component.ts

**Edit** 09.12.2020:
new link to the documentation for headerTemplate input of the column:
https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/column/inputs#headertemplate-templateref

Comment: The link is no longer there, If you could find it and write it here it will be very helpful.